# Why is document.getElementById("item").value so hard to assign to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The way I see it, something like `var thingy = document.getElementById("item").value` should create a variable, put this element's value in it, and call the element's value whenever the variable is called.

I understand that it's not so simple, but I don't understand **why**.

I've read a lot of similar questions considering **global variables** and **page onload**.
The **page unload** seems to explain why linking the HTML page to an external javascript file, but I don't understand why there isn't a simple solution to that.

What makes **assigning a variable** to the element of an **external HTML document** so complicated that people commonly resort to jquery's simple `$()` assignment?

Comment: what's complicated about vanilla JS declaration of getting the value? jQuery essentally rewrites vanilla JS - everything done in jQuery uses JS. So it can be done, and it's not necessarily hard to do, just harder to read (IMO) - I use jQuery because I can't be bothered to learn vanilla JS - but I know I should.

Comment: Are you asking why `thingy` isn't updated if the value of `#item` changes?

Comment: @JLe other way around, actually. When I try to use javascript to update `thingy`, the value in #item stays the same and I get `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("item").value')`. But this only happens if the javascript file is external as opposed to internal.

Answer (score 3):

#### Keeping a "live" reference to an element

`var thingy = document.getElementById("item").value` is copying the value when the line is executed and storing it in `thingy`.

To keep a "live" copy of the value you would store a reference to the element

`var thingy = document.getElementById("item")`

Then you can call later

`thingy.value` to get the current value.

this is comparable to how it sounds like you have been using jQuery

`var thingy = $("#item")`

using `var thingy = $("#item").val()` would produce the same behavior as before of copying the current value and subsequent calls to `thingy` would not be the "live" value.

---

#### Having that reference be not null

Out of the box script tags are parsed synchronously, aka right when they are hit by the parser. Any elements after your script will not be loaded nor be available for querying.

I believe jQuery hooks into the `DOMContentLoaded` event and fires your code once the DOM tree is fully available(all the elements have been parsed). They give you some shorthands for hooking into this event.

```
$(function(){})
$(document).ready(function(){})
jQuery(function($){ });
```

The same is achievable in vanilla.js by hooking into the `DOMContentLoaded` event

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    /* DOM tree fully parsed and available here */
});
```

HTML 5 introduced the [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) attribute to the script tag so we don't have to worry about it at all, our external script will be called after the DOM is parsed. Note that this only applies to external scripts and does not work with internal

```
 <script src="mysite.js" defer></script>
 ....
 /* inside mysite.js */
//DOM ready good to go
var thingy = document.getElementById("item");
```

Comment: I've tried this, but for some reason when I call `thingy.value` from an external javascript file it just returns null, which is the entire point of my question. Have I been doing something wrong?

Comment: Tried to remove my -1. I didn't notice the OP's comments. I can't remove it until you edit your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

When we type out `var thingy = document.getElementById("item").value` You're just getting the current value at that moment. That makes sense because it would be extremely hard to manipulate values and `dom elements` when the values always changing.. When you always want `thingy` to always return the current value you need a function.

```
var thingy = this.getValue();

getValue(){
   return document.getElementById("item").value;
}
```

> What makes assigning a variable to the element of an external HTML
>   document so complicated that people commonly resort to jquery's simple
>   $() assignment?

Nothing. It's just preference.

Edit: Check @Proffesor Allmans answer for more details to your problem. You have to post some code for a solution though.

Comment: I tried your solution, but, as before, I just get `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("item").value')`

Comment: `document.getElementById()` returns `null` if the element couldn't be found.

Comment: How do I figure out what's preventing my element from being found, then?

Comment: You have to show us all of your code. Please edit your question with all the code.

Comment: It's literally just `var thingy = document.getItemById("item").value;` Could there be a problem with declaring variables at the beginning of a javascript file that I'm unaware of?

Comment: show us the html and javascript and the order they are loaded. Either `item` does not exist as a `dom element` or you're calling a refrence to `item` before it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are facing this problem because you are trying to get the element before the dom is fully loaded, whilst jquery work inside function.ready so it waits for the page to be ready